# VBA: Paste data on an index of rows?

Tags: excel, vba

sI'm making a spreadsheet to update Project data for my company. I have code to identify what rows the new data should be inserted on, but am having trouble writing the command to properly paste the new data on the index. My code is:

```
Set wsDest = Worksheets("Projected Hours")
Dim uniqueid As String
Dim rng As Range, c As Range, myRng As Range


'Set range with values to be searched for matches
    Set rng = wsDest.Range("projid")
'Fill string variable with string of text to be matched
    uniqueid = Range("projectid")

'Loop through each cell in range
For Each c In rng
'Check if cell value matches the string to be matched
    If c.Value = uniqueid Then
'Check if this is the first match (new range hasn't been filled yet)
        If myRng Is Nothing Then
'Fill new range with cell
            Set myRng = c
        Else
'Join new matching cell together with previously found matches
            Set myRng = Application.Union(myRng, c)
        End If
    End If
Next c

'Select entire row of each cell in new range
destrows = myRng.Rows

For Each Row In destrows

Range("newprincipal").Copy
    wsDest.Range("D" & destrows()).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Range("newinfo").Copy
    wsDest.Range("F" & destrows()).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Next Row



End Sub
```

Which gives the error "Subscript out of Range" on the first paste line. Am I indexing wrong? What should I change to paste the new information in these specific columns (D and F) in each row of the index? I need the last part to take each value in destrows, which should be a row number and paste my selections into D+(Row Number) and F+(Row Number).

Comment: What is `destrow`? You should get in the habit of using option explicit.

Comment: Couple things - would use a different variable name than `Row` here. If you're looping by row, then you could use `Row.Row`, which would return the row number - but that's why I'd use a different variable name, as that is confusing.

Comment: @sjr it's supposed to be destrows, I forgot to fix that when I copied it over.

Comment: @bigben I'm not very experienced with VBA (if it isn't obvious already haha) by putting Row after For Each does that mean I'm defining it as a variable?

Comment: It is an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of defining my target rows first, I edited my code to paste in my info as it found the correct rows.

```
Sub UpdateProject()

Set wsDest = Worksheets("Projected Hours")
Dim uniqueid As String
Dim rng As Range, c As Range


'Set range with values to be searched for matches
    Set rng = wsDest.Range("projid")
'Fill string variable with string of text to be matched
    uniqueid = Range("projectid")


For Each c In rng
If c.Value = uniqueid Then

Range("newprincipal").Copy
    wsDest.Range("D" & c.Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Range("newinfo").Copy
    wsDest.Range("F" & c.Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End If

Next c




End Sub
```